# Get access token from redirect URL for Instagram in cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, instagram

I have an application using cordova that retrieve user photos after login in Instagram.

In page index.html:

```
<a id="login" href="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MYCLientID&amp;redirect_uri=http://localhost:8200/myphotos.html&amp;response_type=token" >Log into your Instagram</a>
```

in page myphotos.html
I get access token in url then use it.

When i try to run it in ios/android i get error
says:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

while in app setting in Instagram developer
I set `REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:8200/myphotos.html`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Cordova InAppBrowser` plugin to do oauth2 login.

Here is jquery plugin for doing oauth2 login with example, it uses cordova InAppBrowser plugin: https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2

Comment: but what i will insert in redirect url ? as i will use this in android app not website

Comment: yes, this is only meant for android or ios app, you have use cordova  and the InAppBrowser cordova plugin to build app.

Comment: i tried using it but  after i log in it didn't close while i added InAppBrowser plugin

Comment: what cli version are u using ?

Comment: ver " 1.1.1" if there is specific version working with it give me link for required version

Comment: not the plugin version, how are u building the cordova app, what cordova cli version?

Comment: cordova cli version 5.4.1